# Anisotropic filtering on gbuffer textures for shading pass?

Tags: opengl, c++, textures

I have a OpenGL 3.3 deferred shader. 
For my geometry pass I have diffuse textures and/or normal map textures from my models and here I use max anisotropic filtering. But in my shading pass, where the three input textures are position, normal and diffuse textures (the output from geometry pass) - does it even make sense to use anisotropic filtering on these for the shading stage? It wouldn't look any better no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anisotropic filtering is used to diminish aliasing and blur effects of textures that are rendered in planes with angles not oblique (multiple of 90 degrees) in relation with the camera. In the shading pass you will be rendering the light volumes only, which don't have any texture attached to their geometry. Indeed, the only textures you will use are the full-screen position, normal and diffuse textures, which will be oblique in relation with the camera by definition. Thus, anisotropic filtering will not be necessary for this pass.